# Convert HTML table to select with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert a HTML table to a select element with options instead of rows with Javascript. I found ways to do this in reverse and so I came to this HTML:

```js
function showTableData() {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "";
  var myTab = document.getElementById('mytable');

  for (i = 1; i < myTab.rows.length; i++) {
    var objCells = myTab.rows.item(i).cells;
    for (var j = 0; j < objCells.length; j++) {
      info.innerHTML = info.innerHTML + ' ' + objCells.item(j).innerHTML;
    }
    info.innerHTML = '<option>' + info.innerHTML + '</option>';
  }
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;" id="mytable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Vespa</td>
      <td>PX 125</td>
      <td>125 ccm</td>
      <td>M093</td>
      <td>2002 - 2006</td>
      <td><a title="Zu Modell wechseln" href="fahrzeuge/vespa/101-125ccm/px-125-m093">Zu Modell wechseln</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vespa</td>
      <td>PX 125</td>
      <td>125 ccm</td>
      <td>M74</td>
      <td>2010 - 2016</td>
      <td><a title="Zu Modell wechseln" href="fahrzeuge/vespa/101-125ccm/px-125-m74">Zu Modell wechseln</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vespa</td>
      <td>P 125 X</td>
      <td>125 ccm</td>
      <td>VNX1T</td>
      <td>1979 - 1984</td>
      <td><a title="Zu Modell wechseln" href="fahrzeuge/vespa/101-125ccm/p-125-x-vnx1t">Zu Modell wechseln</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vespa</td>
      <td>PX 125</td>
      <td>125 ccm</td>
      <td>VNX2T</td>
      <td>1984 - 1999</td>
      <td><a title="Zu Modell wechseln" href="fahrzeuge/vespa/101-125ccm/px-125-vnx2t">Zu Modell wechseln</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vespa</td>
      <td>PX 125 T5</td>
      <td>125 ccm</td>
      <td>VNX5T</td>
      <td>1985 - 1988</td>
      <td><a title="Zu Modell wechseln" href="fahrzeuge/vespa/101-125ccm/px-125-t5-vnx5t">Zu Modell wechseln</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p><input type="button" id="bt" value="Show Table Data" onclick="showTableData()" /></p>
<select id="info"></select>
```

It works so far, that I get Options but weirdly only the first table row is actually in the last option of the list. I can't see the probably very obviously mistake I'm doing here.

Comment: So you want all the td's in a row to be the option?

Comment: What's `myTab.rows.item(i)`? Why not `myTab.rows.cells(i)`?

Answer (score 0):

1. `info` is not defined
2. `info.innerHTML = '<option>' + info.innerHTML + '</option>';` wraps it in a `option` but you'll need to do that for each `<tr>` instead off after the loop

---

I'd recommend using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop over the `.cells`, then use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to get the text value (needed to get the text in the image)

Then you can use [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to make it a full string, which you can append to the `info` wrapped in an `<option>`

---

So the available options will be:

```
Vespa PX 125 125 ccm M74 2010 - 2016 Zu Modell wechseln
Vespa P 125 X 125 ccm VNX1T 1979 - 1984 Zu Modell wechseln
Vespa PX 125 125 ccm VNX2T 1984 - 1999 Zu Modell wechseln
Vespa PX 125 T5 125 ccm VNX5T 1985 - 1988 Zu Modell wechseln
```

---

Which you can test in this demo:

```js
function showTableData() {
    var myTab = document.getElementById('mytable');
    var info = document.getElementById('info');
    
    info.innerHTML = "";

    for (i = 1; i < myTab.rows.length; i++) {
        var objCells = [ ...myTab.rows.item(i).cells ];
        var texts = objCells.map(o => o.textContent);
        
        info.innerHTML += '<option>' + texts.join(' ') + '</option>';
    }
}

showTableData();
```

```css
table { display: none; }
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;" id="mytable"> <tbody> <tr> <td>Vespa</td> <td>PX 125</td> <td>125 ccm</td> <td>M093</td> <td>2002 - 2006</td> <td><a title="Zu Modell wechseln" href="fahrzeuge/vespa/101-125ccm/px-125-m093">Zu Modell wechseln</a></td> </tr> <tr> <td>Vespa</td> <td>PX 125</td> <td>125 ccm</td> <td>M74</td> <td>2010 - 2016</td> <td><a title="Zu Modell wechseln" href="fahrzeuge/vespa/101-125ccm/px-125-m74">Zu Modell wechseln</a></td> </tr> <tr> <td>Vespa</td> <td>P 125 X</td> <td>125 ccm</td> <td>VNX1T</td> <td>1979 - 1984</td> <td><a title="Zu Modell wechseln" href="fahrzeuge/vespa/101-125ccm/p-125-x-vnx1t">Zu Modell wechseln</a></td> </tr> <tr> <td>Vespa</td> <td>PX 125</td> <td>125 ccm</td> <td>VNX2T</td> <td>1984 - 1999</td> <td><a title="Zu Modell wechseln" href="fahrzeuge/vespa/101-125ccm/px-125-vnx2t">Zu Modell wechseln</a></td> </tr> <tr> <td>Vespa</td> <td>PX 125 T5</td> <td>125 ccm</td> <td>VNX5T</td> <td>1985 - 1988</td> <td><a title="Zu Modell wechseln" href="fahrzeuge/vespa/101-125ccm/px-125-t5-vnx5t">Zu Modell wechseln</a></td> </tr> </tbody> </table>

<select id="info"></select>
```

**Note**: I've removed the button and called the function on load so the options will be visible without any user interaction.